# 1 click Mysql schema to diagram convert?

Tags: mysql, database, schema

I have so many tables and FK relationships it is hard to keep track and visualze it all. Speard across multiple excel documents. I have it already entered in mysql but I want to output a data model diagram that links tables together along with all the FKs.

How to do it apart from manually having to do it? I am open to 3rd part tools as long as they are free.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am using phpMyAdmin on my local server.

[phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) 3 has this Designer feature that shows you the linkages between various tables and its columns.

[image: phpMyAdmin Designer]

Comment: And that is auto-generate from the database like 1 click done or do we need to design it out there?

Comment: Ok i will check it out to see how user friendly it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [MySQL Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/).

It's a free tool and offers a few nice features like forward and backward engineering and database synchronisation. I has a few bugs, but its the best tool for MySQL I know so far.